iOS Background Task Not Executing Despite Proper Registration and Configuration
I am facing an issue with the execution of background tasks in my iOS app using BGTaskScheduler. Despite proper registration and configuration, the BGAppRefreshTask is not getting executed. Here's the relevant part of my code in the AppDelegate:
import UIKit
import Flutter
import BackgroundTasks
import os

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    
    let taskIdentifier = "com.example.nativeBackgroundTaks.backgroundTask"
    
    private var logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "BGTasks")
    
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      
      //Task registrieren
      BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: taskIdentifier, using: nil) { task in
          guard let task = task as? BGAppRefreshTask else {return}
          self.handleTask(task: task)
      }
      
      schedule()
      
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    SwiftPlugin.register(with: registrar(forPlugin: "SwiftPlugin")!)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

    private func handleTask(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
        
        //Updaten des Timestamps der letzten Aktualisierung
        logger.info("BGtask started")
        UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.nativebackgorundwidget")?.set(Date().description, forKey: "last-update")
       
        if let suite = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.nativebackgorundwidget"),
           let lastUpdate = suite.string(forKey: "last-update") {
            logger.info("Letztes Update: \(lastUpdate, privacy: .public)")
        } else {
            logger.info("Kein gültiger Wert für 'last-update' gefunden.")
        }
        
        schedule()
        
        task.expirationHandler = {
            self.logger.info("Task expired")
        }
        
        task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
    }
    
    private func schedule() {
        // Manual Test: e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"com.example.nativeBackgroundTaks.backgroundTask"]
        self.logger.info("start task scheduled")
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.getPendingTaskRequests(completionHandler: { tasks in
            self.logger.info("Running Tasks: \(tasks.count, privacy: .public)")
        })
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.getPendingTaskRequests { requests in
            guard requests.isEmpty else {
                return
            }
            do {
                let newTask = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: self.taskIdentifier)
                newTask.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1 * 60)
                try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(newTask)
                self.logger.info("task scheduled")
            }
            catch {
                self.logger.info("Failed to schedule task: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

}

Despite setting up everything correctly, the task doesn't execute:

I have ensured that the background task registration is done in the right part of the app lifecycle (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions).
I have checked the energy management and ensured that the device is not in low power mode.
The earliestBeginDate is set properly.
I have used the LLDB command for simulating background tasks in the development environment.
Permissions required for background execution have been checked.

Can anyone suggest why iOS might still be refusing to execute this task or if there's anything else I might be missing in this setup?

If you are copying and pasting the test command from the comment, you have a typo in the identifier "NativeBackgroundTaks"
